# Windows 10 Bitlocker Encryption and Storage Space

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption

Does data encrypted by Bitlocker on Windows 10 take up more space than un-encrypted data?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. The encryption is in-place, the data size is the same.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/538094)

Comment: @Burgi I have searched for some sources, but I did not find any. I think it is assumed to be too obvious to be written anywhere.